# Display error message using DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception

My requirement is to write a procedure to add values in `COUNTRIES` table. But, first it should check if corresponding values exist in another table, `REGIONS` as it is a foreign key. Only if the values exist is the insert into `COUNTRIES` table allowed. Otherwise, no.

I wrote a piece of code and its working fine:

```
create or replace procedure addi3 (c_cntry_id  in out countries.country_id%type,
                                   c_cntr_name in countries.country_name%type, 
                                   c_rgn_id    in countries.region_id%type)
is
    region_exists pls_integer;
begin
    begin
        select 1 into region_exists
        from regions r 
        where r.region_id = c_rgn_id;
    exception
      when no_data_found then
        region_exists := 0;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Already present');    
    end;

    if region_exists = 1 then
      insert into countries(country_id, country_name,region_id)
      values (c_cntry_id, c_cntr_name,c_rgn_id);

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserted');
    end if;
end addi3;
/
```

It is working fine, except that if I execute the procedure by giving a `region_id` that does not exist in regions table, it correctly does no insertion in countries table. However, I want to enhance it by throwing an error using `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line` if that `region_id` does not exist and even though I have `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line`, it is not displaying appropriate error message. Can someone please guide?

Comment: do you have SERVEROUTPUT on for your session? if not, you'll have to manually get your 'Already present' or 'Inserted' messages.

Comment: yes,I did: "set serverout on" before executing procedure

Comment: When you say you want it to "throw an error", do you mean you want it to say somegthing other than the current 'Already present'? Or have it actually raise an exception and exit the program?

Comment: yes,say "Already present" in my case when region_id does not exist.(In actuality,it should be "Not present" but I guess that can be corrected once the error message is visible

Comment: If the region doesn't exist - isn't that when its supposed to be doing the insert?

Comment: regions is a foreign table.And no,it should only use data from regions table (in this case region_id being 1,2,3 or 4)

Comment: Right - sorry - it's an existence on an FK, not on the target table. My bad.

Comment: Well, you can always tack on the built-in SQLERRM to your output if you want the oracle message attached { dbms_output.put_line('Region does not exist '||sqlerrm); }, then if you want the code to raise an actual exception, you can just {RAISE; } to raise the NO_DATA_FOUND to the calling code.

Comment: tx,can u please edit my original code to write this? I am new to oracle

Comment: listen to @MichaelBroughton, you want to do ACTUAL error tracking, not by  using DBMS_OUTPUT. i'm running your code and am seeing the output messages though.

Comment: Strange. Why am I not seeing messages? I also have set serverout on.How are you executing the procedure?

Comment: First - we can't answer why you aren't seeing output without knowing what client you are using. Second, I would caution that code like this to check for FKs is generally a bad idea. Put a proper constraint at the DB level, attempt the insert, and if the client tries to insert a bad region the constraint error will be raised to the client. You duplicating something that the DB does faster and better is a waste of resources and adds unnecessary code complexity in almost every case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An edit of your code per your request in comments:

```
create or replace procedure addi3 (c_cntry_id in out countries.country_id%type,
                                       c_cntr_name in countries.country_name%type, 
                                       c_rgn_id in countries.region_id%type)
is
    region_exists pls_integer;
begin
    begin
        select 1 into region_exists
        from regions r 
        where r.region_id = c_rgn_id;
    exception
        when no_data_found then
            region_exists := 0;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Region not present '||sqlerrm);
            -- uncomment the RAISE if you want the exception to be
            -- propagated back to the calling code.
            --RAISE;

    end;
    -- if you uncommented the RAISE the IF here is redundant
    -- because you wouldn't have got here if the region didn't exist.
    if region_exists = 1 then
         insert into countries(country_id, country_name,region_id)
         values (c_cntry_id, c_cntr_name, c_rgn_id);
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserted');
     end if;
end addi3;
/
```